# JSON.NET MVC 4 WebApi proper return type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I see different examples of different return types for WebApi Controller.Method.

1. [Customizing JSON.NET serialization](http://tostring.it/2012/07/18/customize-json-result-in-web-api/)- Get method returns HttpResponseMessage
2. [using JSON.NET in ASP.NET MVC](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net.aspx) - shows ActionResult (I understand it is outdated article)
3. Web Api Tutorial returns Business object

I wonder what are the guidelines when to return what?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on your requirement.

when you return HttpResponseMessage, it gives you options to return HttpStatusCode with a custom message.

Say for example, in your application, you are saving something through web api (say a new customer for example). you can return that object with the message as well pretty easily and you don't have to worry about the return type (json or xml) at all. And this will be an answer for your 3rd point as well. This is the better way to send a business object to the frontend in web api.

as an answer to the 3rd point, please take a look at this blog post for more info. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/10/13/asp-net-web-api-help-page-part-2-providing-custom-samples-on-the-help-page.aspx

in a web api action which return an HttpResponseMessage, the return code would look something like this.

```
return Request.CreateResponse<Customer>(HttpStatusCode.Created, newlyCreatedCustomer);
```

The second post doesn't mention anything about web api. It shows a way to return json data if you ever want to do it in the Controller Action.

Comment: I saw opinions that returning HttpResponseMessage does not allow good testing... which I agree hence method can return pretty much anything inside of HttpResponseMessage..... What do you think?

Comment: Yes, writing a test for an action which return HttpResponseMessage is a bit tricky as it expect lot of configurations. Please take a look at this blog post, it will shine some light on it http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/16/unit-testing-asp-dot-net-web-api/